# Intersection of multiple lists with IEnumerable.Intersect()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of lists which I want to find the intersection for like this:

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4 };
var list3 = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5 };
var listOfLists = new List<List<int>>() { list1, list2, list3 };

// expected intersection is List<int>() { 3 };
```

Is there some way to do this with IEnumerable.Intersect()?

EDIT:
I should have been more clear on this: I really have a list of lists, I don't know how many there will be, the three lists above was just an example, what I have is actually an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SomeClass>>`

### SOLUTION

Thanks for all great answers. It turned out there were four options for solving this: **List+aggregate** (@Marcel Gosselin), **List+foreach** (@JaredPar, @Gabe Moothart), **HashSet+aggregate** (@jesperll) and **HashSet+foreach** (@Tony the Pony). I did some performance testing on these solutions (varying **number of lists**, **number of elements** in each list and **random number max** size.

It turns out that for most situations the HashSet performs better than the List (except with large lists and small random number size, because of the nature of HashSet I guess.)
I couldn't find any real difference between the foreach method and the aggregate method (the foreach method performs *slightly* better.)

To me, the aggregate method is really appealing (and I'm going with that as the accepted answer) but I wouldn't say it's the most readable solution.. Thanks again all!

Answer (score 97, accepted):

How about:

```
var intersection = listOfLists
    .Skip(1)
    .Aggregate(
        new HashSet<T>(listOfLists.First()),
        (h, e) => { h.IntersectWith(e); return h; }
    );
```

That way it's optimized by using the same HashSet throughout and still in a single statement. Just make sure that the listOfLists always contains at least one list.

Comment: Wow, No way that I could have think myself about this solution. Once you have the solution, it seems obvious.....hummmm, no, I will leave a comment just to be sure my coworkers will not think that I take too much weed :)

Comment: functional paradigm wins )

Comment: why is there a need for the Skip?  Asking because I don't know

Comment: Skip is there because the first element is used for the initial populate of the hashset. You must do this, because otherwise it's a bunch of intersections with an empty set.

Comment: I understand the solution. I guess e stands for enumerator? Can I also ask what h stands for? I guess h stands for HashSet?

Comment: @Quan h is the accumulator for the aggregate method, which is the same type as the seed (1st argument). Since the seed is a `HashSet`, it gets abbreviated to h. e is the next element to be used with the accumulator h.

Answer (score 73):

You can indeed use `Intersect` twice. However, I believe this will be more efficient:

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(list1);
hashSet.IntersectWith(list2);
hashSet.IntersectWith(list3);
List<int> intersection = hashSet.ToList();
```

Not an issue with small sets of course, but if you have a lot of large sets it could be significant.

Basically `Enumerable.Intersect` needs to create a set on each call - if you know that you're going to be doing more set operations, you might as well keep that set around.

As ever, keep a close eye on performance vs readability - the method chaining of calling `Intersect` twice is very appealing.

EDIT: For the updated question:

```
public List<T> IntersectAll<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> lists)
{
    HashSet<T> hashSet = null;
    foreach (var list in lists)
    {
        if (hashSet == null)
        {
            hashSet = new HashSet<T>(list);
        }
        else
        {
            hashSet.IntersectWith(list);
        }
    }
    return hashSet == null ? new List<T>() : hashSet.ToList();
}
```

Or if you know it won't be empty, and that Skip will be relatively cheap:

```
public List<T> IntersectAll<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> lists)
{
    HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>(lists.First());
    foreach (var list in lists.Skip(1))
    {
        hashSet.IntersectWith(list);
    }
    return hashSet.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the foreach makes sense. Any performance difference with this compared to the Aggregate method in Marcel's answer?

Comment: @Oskar: Yes, my answer uses a single hashset instead of creating a new one each time. However, you could still use Aggregate with a set... will edit.

Comment: Ick... just tried to work out an Aggregate solution, and it's icky because HashSet.IntersectWith returns null :(

Comment: Hi. One question regarding your `IntersectAll()` method (which is handful) : is there a simple way to add a selector as parameter, to compare values (eg : `Func<TResult, TKey> selector`) and still use `InsertectWith()` ?

Comment: @tigrou: Not terribly easily - because you'd still want to return a `List<T>` rather than a `List<TKey>`, right? The best approach would probably be to create an `EqualityComparer<T>` which was implemented by projecting to `TKey`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Do you mean something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909259/generic-iequalitycomparert-and-gethashcode ? (and passing the `GenericEqualitycomparer<T>` instance to `HashSet<T>` constructor)

Comment: @tigrou: That's not how I'd build it - I'd use a `ProjectionEqualityComparer` that took a `Func<T, TKey>` and used that for equality and hashing... but yes, that's the general shape.

Comment: One question : is returning a `List<T>()` done on purpose (to fit OP example or avoid some unexpected behavior) ? will it be a good idea to return a IEnumerable<T> instead and yield the results from the HashSet ?

Comment: @tigrou: I honestly can't remember why I happened to do it that way five years ago...

Answer (score 36):

Try this, it works but I'd really like to get rid of the .ToList() in the aggregate.

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 2, 3, 4 };
var list3 = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5 };
var listOfLists = new List<List<int>>() { list1, list2, list3 };
var intersection = listOfLists.Aggregate((previousList, nextList) => previousList.Intersect(nextList).ToList());
```

**Update:**

Following comment from @pomber, it is possible to get rid of the `ToList()` inside the `Aggregate` call and move it outside to execute it only once. I did not test for performance whether previous code is faster than the new one. The change needed is to specify the generic type parameter of the `Aggregate` method on the last line like below:

```
var intersection = listOfLists.Aggregate<IEnumerable<int>>(
   (previousList, nextList) => previousList.Intersect(nextList)
   ).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that out and it works! Havn't used Aggregate() before but I guess it was something like this I was looking for.

Comment: As I have specified as a comment on Tony's answer, I believe his solution will perform better.

Comment: You can get rid of the .ToList() in the aggregate if you use Aggregate<IEnumerable<int>>

Comment: @pomber, I can't believe your comment has gone 3 years without an upvote. Well today is your day my friend.

Answer (score 8):

You could do the following

```
var result = list1.Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really have a list of lists, not three separate lists.. I need something that works independent of how many lists there are in listOfLists.

Comment: @Oskar You could easily run that in a loop

Answer (score 6):

This is my version of the solution with an extension method that I called IntersectMany.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> IntersectMany<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if(!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return new TResult[0];

        var ret = selector(enumerator.Current);

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            ret = ret.Intersect(selector(enumerator.Current));
        }

        return ret;
    }
}
```

So the usage would be something like this:

```
var intersection = (new[] { list1, list2, list3 }).IntersectMany(l => l).ToList();
```

Comment: `IntersectMany` great idea!  I love it.

Answer (score 2):

This is my one-row solution for List of List (ListOfLists) without intersect function:

```
var intersect = ListOfLists.SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct().Where(w=> ListOfLists.TrueForAll(t=>t.Contains(w))).ToList()
```

This should work for .net 4 (or later)

Answer (score 0):

After searching the 'net and not really coming up with something I liked (or that worked), I slept on it and came up with this. Mine uses a class (`SearchResult`) which has an `EmployeeId` in it and that's the thing I need to be common across lists. I return all records that have an `EmployeeId` in every list. It's not fancy, but it's simple and easy to understand, just what I like. For small lists (my case) it should perform just fine—and anyone can understand it!

```
private List<SearchResult> GetFinalSearchResults(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<SearchResult>> lists)
{
    Dictionary<int, SearchResult> oldList = new Dictionary<int, SearchResult>();
    Dictionary<int, SearchResult> newList = new Dictionary<int, SearchResult>();

    oldList = lists.First().ToDictionary(x => x.EmployeeId, x => x);

    foreach (List<SearchResult> list in lists.Skip(1))
    {
        foreach (SearchResult emp in list)
        {
            if (oldList.Keys.Contains(emp.EmployeeId))
            {
                newList.Add(emp.EmployeeId, emp);
            }
        }

        oldList = new Dictionary<int, SearchResult>(newList);
        newList.Clear();
    }

    return oldList.Values.ToList();
}
```

Here's an example just using a list of ints, not a class (this was my original implementation).

```
static List<int> FindCommon(List<List<int>> items)
{
    Dictionary<int, int> oldList = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    Dictionary<int, int> newList = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    oldList = items[0].ToDictionary(x => x, x => x);

    foreach (List<int> list in items.Skip(1))
    {
        foreach (int i in list)
        {
            if (oldList.Keys.Contains(i))
            {
                newList.Add(i, i);
            }
        }

        oldList = new Dictionary<int, int>(newList);
        newList.Clear();
    }

    return oldList.Values.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a simple solution if your lists are all small. If you have larger lists, it's not as performing as hash set:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectMany<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> input)
{
    if (!input.Any())
        return new List<T>();

    return input.Aggregate(Enumerable.Intersect);
}
```