# Intersect a collection of collections in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a list of lists which I want to intersect:

```
List<List<int>> input = new List<List<int>>();
input.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 5, 8 });
input.Add(new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5 });
input.Add(new List<int>() { 1, 4, 5, 6 });
```

Output should be:

```
{ 4, 5 }
```

How can this be accomplished in a terse fashion?

Comment: Do you need to be using Lists? why not use Hashsets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersection of multiple lists with IEnumerable.Intersect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var result = input.Cast<IEnumerable<int>>().Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y))
```

Comment: Sorry for making a mistake the first time, I forgot I would have to cast down to `IEnumerable<int>`.