# intersect two lists with different objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of ObjA and ObjB as follows:

```
List<ObjA> List1;
List<ObjB> List2;
```

Both ObjA and ObjB has a common field which is User and I want to intersect them based on User.Id.

```
class ObjA
{ 
  User user;
  .... other properties
}

class ObjB
{ 
  User user;
  .... other properties
}

class User
{
    int Id;
     .... other props
}
```

How can i intersect these two lists on User.Id with linq?

**As a result I want only the list of Users.**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The general idea is

```
var commonUsers = list1.Select(a => a.User).Intersect(list2.Select(b => b.User));
```

However, by itself this assumes that `User` implements `IEquatable<User>`, which does not seem to be the case here. So you either need to add this implementation or use the `Intersect` overload that accepts a custom [`IEqualityComparer<User>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151).

Comment: And then use `commonUsers` to filter both lists.

Comment: @Oded: That doesn't seem to be what he's after.

Comment: If you do want the results from one (or both) lists, and not just commonUsers, a join works well. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5468803/329301

Answer (score 12):

1.look at this simple code

```
  var result = (from objA in objAList
                join objB in objBList on objA.user.Id equals objB.user.Id
                select objA/*or objB*/).ToList();
```

2.complete code

```
 class QueryJoin
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //create users
        User user1 = new User { Id = 1, Name = "anuo1" };
        User user2 = new User { Id = 2, Name = "anuo2" };
        User user3 = new User { Id = 3, Name = "anuo3" };
        User user4 = new User { Id = 4, Name = "anuo4" };
        User user5 = new User { Id = 5, Name = "anuo5" };
        //create objAList
        List<ObjA> objAList = new List<ObjA>();
        objAList.Add(new ObjA { user = user1 });
        objAList.Add(new ObjA { user = user2 });
        objAList.Add(new ObjA { user = user3 });
        //create objBList
        List<ObjB> objBList = new List<ObjB>();
        objBList.Add(new ObjB { user = user3 });
        objBList.Add(new ObjB { user = user4 });
        objBList.Add(new ObjB { user = user5 });

        //intersect
        var result = (from objA in objAList
                      join objB in objBList on objA.user.Id equals objB.user.Id
                      select objA/*or objB*/).ToList();

    }

}

class ObjA
{
    public User user { get; set; }
}

class ObjB
{
    public User user { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

without need of IEqualityComparer or IEquatable (which would be better anyway)

```
var commonUsers = list1
                  .Select(l1 => l1.User)
                  .Where(u => list1
                       .Select(l => l.User.Id)
                       .Intersect(list2
                          .Select(l2 => l2.Id))
                       .Contains(u.Id));
```

or

```
var commonUsers = list1.Select(l1 => l1.User)
                      .Where(u=> list2.Select(l2 => l2.User.Id)
                                        .Contains(u.Id));
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard way is to utilize an `IEqualityComparer` object. The default one uses the standard equality comparison. Create a class that implements the `IEqualityComparer` interface and performs the comparison you want. Then you can call an overload of `IEnumerable.Intersect` that accepts an instance of your custom compare class

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension method Linq

`var result = List1.Join(List2, e1 => e1.ID, e2 => e2.ID, (e1, e2)=> e1);`

For more information , you can visite https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-joining-operator-join