# C# LINQ to Entities query for the intersection of two different properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 3 models named:

> **Pencil** having Pencil.Id(int) and Pencil.Colors(IEnumerable) Property
>
> **Pen** having Pen.Id(int) and Pen.Colors(IEnumerable) Property
>
> **Colors** having Id and name.

Pencil has a relation with colors (many-to-many)
Pen has a relation with colors (many-to-many)

I want to build a query which will show me the same colored pencils for the pen that I am holding.

I am using the below LINQ-to-Entities query:

```
int id = id_of_the_pen_that_i_am_holding;
Pen p = db.Pens.Find(id);
var list = from m in db.Pencils where m.Colors.Intersect(p.Colors) != null select m;
```

Colors model is IEnumerable so it has more than 1 color. For example; the pen has 15 different colors and pencil is having 25 different colors. I want to bring the corresonding pencil if one of the colors of the pen that I am holding is also avaialable in the color palette of that pencil.

But I am getting an exception to use regular variables like int or string rather than objects.

What can I do? Thanks in advance for your helps.

**EDITED:**
I've created a new question for a next possible issue: [C# LINQ to Entities- Properties on the intersection of an object and a collection of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760499/c-sharp-linq-to-entities-properties-on-the-intersection-set)

Comment: Are you not over complicating this?  Think back to plain SQL (which is what your query will be converted to anyway) can you not instead just say from m in db.Pencils where m.Color = p.Color select m?

Comment: Color model is IEnumerable so it has more than 1 color. For example A pen has 15 different colors and a pen has 25 different colors. I want to see if one of the colors of the pen is also avaialable in the color scale of the pencil.

Comment: If your color property is enumerable, then maybe name `Colors` or `Palette` will better describe it's intent.

Comment: Have you tried making Color implement IEquatable<Color>?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285045/intersect-two-lists-with-different-objects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int id = id_of_the_pen_that_i_am_holding;
Pen p = db.Pens.Find(id);
var penColorIds = p.Color.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
var list = db.Pencils.Where(pencil => pencil.Color.Any(color => penColorIds.Contains(color.Id));
```

Comment: Hey Raphael. How about getting the list of the colors in the intersection set? I will appreciate if you have a solution for this also.

Comment: I've just created a new question for this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760499/c-sharp-linq-to-entities-properties-on-the-intersection-set

Answer (score 0):

What about simplifying your code and doing it this way, I know it's not particularly elegant but I'm not sure (off the top of my head) whether LINQ has a **nice** way of doing what you want:

```
IList<Pencil> sameColorPencils = new List<Pencil>();

Pen p = db.Pens.Find(id);

foreach (Color color in p.Color)
{
    var pencils = from pencil in db.Pencils
                  where pencil.Color == color
                  select pencil;

    foreach (Pencil pencil in pencils)
    {
        if (sameColorPencils.Count(e => e.Id == pencil.Id) == 0)
        {
            sameColorPencils.Add(pencils);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It is a good approach but I don't know if its performance is good enough. It seems logical but I prefer a direct LINQ query rather than loops.