# C# LINQ to Entities- Properties on the intersection of an object and a collection of objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I used to ask a similar question which was aiming to understand how to get the models at the other set which are having the same property with the one I am holding.

Now the problem is:
So, what was the name of the "similar property" which actually guided me to the other set.

The original post was:
[C# LINQ to Entities query for the intersection of two different properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722084/c-sharp-linq-to-entities-query-for-the-intersection-of-two-different-properties)

I have 3 models named:

1. Pencil having Pencil.Id(int) and Pencil.Colors(IEnumerable) Property
2. Pen having Pen.Id(int) and Pen.Colors(IEnumerable) Property
3. Colors having Id and name.

Colors model is IEnumerable so it has more than 1 color. For example; the pen has 15 different colors and pencil is having 25 different colors. I want to bring the corresonding pencil if one of the colors of the pen that I am holding is also avaialable in the color palette of that pencil.

**Raphael**'s great solution is https://stackoverflow.com/a/11722191/1062284

```
int id = id_of_the_pen_that_i_am_holding;
Pen p = db.Pens.Find(id);
var penColorIds = p.Color.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
var list = db.Pencils.Where(pencil => pencil.Color.Any(color => penColorIds.Contains(color.Id));
```

So it is OK and working like a charm but how about learning the name of the common colors?
We get the other properties which are holding the same color but what was that color?

I will appreciate if some one can produce this LINQ query. I am pretty new for LINQ and will much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are holding multiple pens in your hand then use  (in variable `pens`)

```
var colors = pens.SelectMany(p=>p.Colors).Distinct(); 
var commonColors = db.Pencils.SelectMany (p => p.Colors.Where(c=>colors.Contains(c))).Distinct()
```

Else if you only have one pen (in variable `pen`)

```
var colors = pen.Colors;
var commonColors = db.Pencils.SelectMany (p => p.Colors.Where(c=>colors.Contains(c))).Distinct()
```

Comment: It was giving a solution for the combination of 2 of the questions and very need. But you are right, The first answer was yours and answering all the requirements of the question. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) extension on the colors reduced with the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) extension.

```
var commonColors = 
    db.Pens.SelectMany(p => p.Colors)
        .Insersect(db.Pencils.SelectMany(hb => hb.Colors));
```

---

Since `Intersct` probably returns a sequence, not a set, (I haven't checked) you could remove duplicates like this

```
var commonColors = 
    db.Pens.SelectMany(p => p.Colors).Distinct()
        .Insersect(db.Pencils.SelcectMany(hb => hb.Colors).Distinct());
```

---

For just one `Pen` do

```
Pen p = db.Pens.Find(id); 
var commonColors = Pen.Colors
    .Insersect(db.Pencils.SelcectMany(p => p.Colors));
```

Comment: Great but I am looking for the intersection of the pen's(which I am holding) common colors and the rest of the pencils. So, the pen is only an object and pencils is a collection. Will this work for this scenario also?

Comment: var commonColors = db.Pencils.SelectMany(p => p.Colors).Distinct().Insersect(Pen.Colors).Distinct()); didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, not sure it makes really sense to get all in one query, but, with this, you should get a  list of anonymous object of pencil and a list of common colors for each pencil (untested).

```
int id = id_of_the_pen_that_i_am_holding;
Pen p = db.Pens.Find(id);
var penColorIds = p.Color.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();

var list = db.Pencils.Where(pencil => pencil.Color.Any(color => penColorIds.Contains(color.Id))
.Select(l => new {
   pencil = l,
   colors = l.Color.Where(c => penColorIds.Contains(c.Id))
});
```

Comment: RESPECT Raphael. It was really great. Again you did it. I think it is the best solution for the combination of 2 but Bob's answer was also working and he was the first one answering. I hope you will understand.

Comment: @MrGorki no prob, that's the right way to do, nothing to understand ;)