# search in text delimited field using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, delimiter

I have a field which is that consists from delimiter (dynamic number) parts:

```
(c44 EE0),(c2 EE7),(e79 EE10),(c2 EE90)
```

my field is a comma delimiter field and  how can i split it (in Linq) and search in the parts separately?

**i.e. query : get those parts which have C2**

please let me describe my problem again i have a field in sql server which i want to get result of that via LINQ ,

above field named **code** in SNP table as you can see this code field is tab delimited so
i would like to catch those records which have C2 in their at least one part.
Its simple to split a field via 'comma delimiter' but how can i do this in a linq query?

Comment: you mean line.split(..) i know it and number of characters, but  please tell me how can gather those () which have like C2

Comment: by any chance you mean string[]?

Answer (score 2):

```
var field = "(c44 EE0),(c2 EE7),(e79 EE10),(c2 EE90)";
var result = field.Split(',').Where(x => x.Contains("c2"));
```

Comment: how can get query like this if have multiple target text like : `var query = (from c in db.SNPs where c.Effect.Split(',').Where(x =>.Contains("c2") || x.Contains("c4")) select c);`

Comment: have a look at Intersect http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285045/intersect-two-lists-with-different-objects Might be a good idea to create a new question.

Comment: for this code `var query = (from c in db.SNPs  where c.Effect.Split(',').Any(x => x.Contains("C2"))
select c).ToArray();`  i faced with this error **The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'System.String'. Actual 'System.String[]'.** how can i handle string Array??

Comment: @user3616494   what exactly do you need to come out of the query? by your example you are selecting the whole object(in this case SNPs objects).

Comment: please let me describe my problem again i have a field in sql server which i want to get result of that via LINQ ,

above field named code in SNP table as you can see this code field is tab delimited so i would like to catch those records which have C2 in their at least one part. Its simple to split a field via 'comma delimiter' but how can i do this in a linq query?