# Comparing custom objects c#

Tags: c#, list

I have the following situation:

I have a loop which could loop any amount of times. Within that loop I am calling a method which returns a `List<CustomClass>` After I have run through the loop I need to be able to compare all the `List<CustomClass>` items from each list and see which ones are common between all of them. In order to do this I have tried to put all the `List<CustomClass>` into another list: `List<List<CustomClass>` and then I need to use all of these to see which ones exist in all of them. I will be comparing on one property of my CustomClass (string Name)

This is what I have so far

```
public class CustomClass
{
    public string name;
}

public List<CustomClass> SomeMethod()
{
    List<List<CustomClass>> bigList = new List<List<CustomClass>>();
    List<CustomClass> finalList = new List<CustomClass>();
    for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {            
        List<List<CustomClass>> newList = GetNewList();
        bigList.Add(newList);
    }
    //I now need to compare everything in bigList and create a new list with all common 
    //items in the list of bigList.
    return finalList ;
}

public List<CustomClass> GetNewList()
{
    List<CustomClass> newList = new List<CustomClass>();
    for (int i=0;i<=5;i++)
    {            
        CustomClass newClass = new CustomClass();
        newClass.name = "some name";
        newList.Add(newClass);
    }
    return newList;
{
```

I hope this makes sense. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit**

For example in `List<List<CustomClass>>` each `List<CustomClass>` contains a CustomClass with name set to "Pete", I then want to create a CustomClass with name set to "Pete" and add it to the final list.

Comment: Please define *common items in the list of bigList*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> see which ones are common between all of them

Use the `Intersect` extension method:

```
var common = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

Note that for this to work, you should either:

- override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `CustomClass`
- make `CustomClass` implement `IEquatable<CustomClass>`
- provide `Intersect` with a custom comparer that implements `IEqualityComparer<CustomClass>`

Comment: Thanks for that, lead me on the right path. This person proabably asked it in a better way than I did :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect