# List.Where passing in object of different type (Predicates)

Tags: c#, linq, list, where-clause, predicate

I've got a list of objects of type `A`. Each object has a `Name` property. I have an object of type `B` that also has a `Name` property where I wanted to use this `B.Name` to match the objects in `List<A>` that have the same name.

Is this possible using `List.Where` with a custom predicate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5788079/284240

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, unless I'm missing a subtle point of your request:

```
var filtered = listOfAs.Where(a => a.Name == b.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
myListOfAs.Where(a=>a.Name == myB.Name);
```

This will return an IEnumerable of zero or more elements of myListOfAs that have the same name as a particular B instance myB.

You can also use a Join() to match multiple Bs in a second list with elements that have matching names from the list of As, but that doesn't sound like what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, I think you just want a join.  This is easiest to do with the query syntax:

```
var results = from a in ListA
              join b in ListB on a.Name equals b.Name
              select { whatever you need from a and b };
```

Comment: I don't think there is a list of `B`s.

Comment: Ah yes.  Apparently I didn't understand the question :)