# I have multiple list objects in one list, how can i get the items that exist in every child list?

Tags: c#

Starting with a basic class:

```
public class Car
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I can then create a list of these cars

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
```

The new step is to have a List of this List, like this:

```
List<List<Car>> allListsOfCars = new List<List<Car>>();
```

After populating allListsOfCars, I want to pass it to a function which will return me the cars which exist in every List list.

I know it sounds confusing, so I'll try explain a bit more.

If I have ListA, ListB, ListC all of type List - and now combine these into 1 holding list(The list of a list), then how can I get back all the cars that exist in every list? For example if a car only exists in ListA, then I'm not interested, it needs to exist in ListA AND ListB AND ListC, then I want it added to the result set and returned.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yo dawg, I herd you like listing lists of cars so we put cars in yo lists and lists of cars in yo lists so you can drive while u iterate while u iterate.

Comment: @BoltClock, yeah quite a mouthful, but heh, it makes sense if you read it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to find the composite intersection of all the sublists.

```
IEnumerable<Car> result=allListsOfCars.FirstOrDefault();
if(result!=null)
{
    foreach(var sublist in allListsOfCars.Skip(1))
    {
        result=result.Intersect(sublist);
    }
    //enumerate result to run the query
}
```

It might be possible to [rewrite using the `Aggregate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect/1676684#1676684) operator to eliminate the loop, but `Aggregate` never reads very well IMO.

If the lists are long, you'll probably get a decent speed increase using a `HashSet`

```
IEnumerable<Car> fst=allListsOfCars.FirstOrDefault();
if(result!=null)
{
    HashSet<Car> hs=new HashSet<Car>(fst);
    foreach(var sublist in allListsOfCars.Skip(1))
    {
        hs.IntersectWith(sublist); //in-place operation
    }
    //enumerate hs
}
```

Make sure that you `Car` class implements equality members and `GetHashCode` correctly, otherwise neither of these approaches will work as expected.

Comment: I LOVE this approach. Basically you start from the first list of cars, which HAVE to contain all the shared cars. Then intersect it with all other lists.

Comment: Please explain the theory behind this?

Comment: It simply finds the intersection of several lists, which gives you the items that are common to all lists.

Comment: @Splender, so after the loop is run, how would you get the result back into a List object?

Comment: In the first case `result.ToList()` or the second `hs.ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to .NET 3.5 or later you can do the following:

```
IEnumerable<Car> carList = allListsOfCar.SelectMany(cars => cars);
```

EDIT:

To do the intersection of the lists you can do:

```
List<Car> carList = allListsOfCar.Aggregate((left, right) => left.Intersect(right).ToList());
```

Comment: You didn't answer the "how can I get back all the cars that exist in every list" part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregate and I think this is a very real use case for it:

```
var allCars = allListOfCars.Aggregate((listAcc,list2)=> listAcc.Concat(list2).ToList());
```

Bascially, for each element ( which in this case is a List<> ) concat it to the accumulator, getting a single list in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same approach as Adam, but expanded it a little.

```
IEnumerable<Car> carList = listCars.SelectMany(cars => cars);

List<Car> repeatedCars = new List<Car>();

int length = listCars.Count;

foreach (Car c in cars1)
{
    int numberRepeats = carList.Count(car => car.Name == c.Name);
    if (numberRepeats == length)
    {
        repeatedCars.Add(c);
    }
}
```

Basically you need to know how many lists you have and save them all in a single list.
Then just iterate through the first list of cars (or any of them) and count the number of cars with the same name in the list with all of the other lists. If the length and the number of repeats is the same, then that car is in all of the lists.

Comment: Also oxilumin's approach is not really recommended, triple foreach will take a long time to process.

Comment: You've also written a triple foreach loop; your two inner ones are just disguised as `SelectMany`.

Comment: Yeah, but mine aren't nested. At least not all 3 of them.

Comment: They are, in fact, nested. Every time through your `foreach` loop it iterates over the `SelectMany` results.