# get common elements in lists in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two sorted lists as below:

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 2, 4 };
```

I want the output to be: `{1, 1, 2}`

How to do this in C#?
Is there a way using Linq?

Comment: What about 3 in your example?

Comment: That was a mistake. Please refer updated version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intersection of multiple lists with IEnumerable.Intersect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The extra 1 means you can't use `Intersect` because it returns a set.

Here's some code that does what you need:

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 2, 4 };

var grouped1 =
    from n in list1
    group n by n
    into g
    select new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()};

var grouped2 =
    from n in list2
    group n by n
    into g
    select new {g.Key, Count = g.Count()};

var joined =
    from b in grouped2
    join a in grouped1 on b.Key equals a.Key
    select new {b.Key, Count = Math.Min(b.Count, a.Count)};

var result = joined.SelectMany(a => Enumerable.Repeat(a.Key, a.Count));

CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new[] {1, 1, 2}, result);
```

Answer (score 46):

Use [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx):

```
 var commonElements = list1.Intersect(list2).ToList();
```

Comment: How would you invert this? i.e get uncommon elements.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - What do you mean by uncommon? Do you mean [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx)??

Comment: @Manoj: list1.Except(list2).ToList();

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: with intersect the output is {1,2} but I want {1, 1, 2}.

Comment: Your solution does not work for what he wants, it outputs {1,2} no {1,1,2}

Answer (score 3):

This works nicely:

```
var list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
var list2 = new List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 2, 4 };

var lookup1 = list1.ToLookup(x => x);
var lookup2 = list2.ToLookup(x => x);

var results = lookup1.SelectMany(l1s => lookup2[l1s.Key].Zip(l1s, (l2, l1) => l1));
```

Comment: Should be the accepted solution.  While @Austin Salonen answer works, this solution is far more elegant.  More concise and _relatively_ easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

While both @Austin Salonen's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808047/1243753) and @Enigmativity's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944095/1243753) work for any given lists, neither take advantage of OP's condition that the lists are **sorted**.

Given that both lists will be ordered we can do a search in `O(n + m)` time where n and m are the length of each list.  Not entirely sure what the previous solutions big o performance is, but it's definitely slower then `O(n + m)`.

Basically we just walk both lists, moving one or both enumerators based on a comparison check.

```
var results = new List<int>();
var e1 = list1.GetEnumerator();
var e2 = list2.GetEnumerator();
var hasNext = e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext();

while (hasNext) {
    var value1 = e1.Current;
    var value2 = e2.Current;

    if (value1 == value2) {
        results.Add(value1);
        hasNext = e1.MoveNext() && e2.MoveNext();
    } else if (value1 < value2) {
        hasNext = e1.MoveNext();
    } else if (value1 > value2) {
        hasNext = e2.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

That's it! `results` will be an empty list if no matches are found.
Note this assumes both lists are in ascending order.  If it's descending, just flip the `<` and `>` operators.

Answer (score -2):

I am late in answering this question, this might help future visitors.

```
            List<int> p = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 2, 3 };
            List<int> q = new List<int> { 1, 1, 2, 2, 4 };
            List<int> x = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < p.Count; i++ )
            {
                if (p[i] == q[i])
                {
                    x.Add(p[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's just a fluke that the positions match. The OP is after the occurrences not the positions.