# How to find exact group of selected list items using linq

Tags: linq

Lets say we have some values in a table like below with id vaues: 1 = animal, 2=carnivorous, 3=herbivorous

animals

name----------propertyId

cat ----------------1
dog ---------------1
rabbit--------------1

cat-----------------2
dog----------------2
rabbit--------------3

how can i select propertyId of values like:

cat&dog&rabbit ---> 1 (animal)

cat&dog      ---> 2 (carnivorous)

Edit: Rabbit. Thanks Vland :)

Comment: if rabbit is = 2 (carnivorous), why shouldn't it be selected?

Comment: @Vland, some rabbits are carnivorous ;) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcxKIJTb3Hg

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz, could you please clarify your question? Are you trying to get the properties that are common to a group of animals? or just group the animals by property?

Comment: Actually i have a list of selectlist items and i want to find the group id of selected items. I don't know there will be how many selectlists or options.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that i was looking for intersection of multiple lists like
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect). First i am getting all propertyId's of a property and then the others, finally intersection.
This is the only solution which works for now.