# C# find a number common to two or more lists

Tags: c#, linq

What is the syntax for finding a list of numbers both present in two or more List? I was looping through when I only needed to check two lists, but now I need to do several...
Something like

```
List<int> commonIds = SELECT id from list1 
                     where list1.contains(id), 
                           list2.contains(id), 
                           list3.contains(id) ...
```

Comment: All lists or any two lists?

Comment: Hi, there is solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect

Comment: @Yuval "two or more lists", not "all the lists"

Comment: I'm going to need to do up to 5 I think.

Comment: @Rawling I don't understand what you mean? He wants to intersect multiple lists.

Comment: @PawelMaga Yes, thank you. I missed that before when looking.

Comment: do you mean the union of the intersects of all the two set combinations?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov From the title I was leaning towards "present in two or more of these three lists" but I honestly can't be sure now.

Answer (score 3):

#### Finding the intersection of any number of lists

If you want to find the set of numbers that exist in *all* of the lists then `Enumerable.Intersect` is a good way to do so. You don't even have to hardcode the collection of lists, it can be created at runtime:

```
var lists = new[] { list1, list2, ..., listN }; // dynamically specified

var common = lists.First().AsEnumerable();
foreach (var list in lists.Skip(1))
{
    common = common.Intersect(list);
}

// and now common has the result, e.g.
var listOfCommonEntries = common.ToList();
```

#### Finding the union of intersections between master list and each other one

If you want to find the set which includes all common numbers between list 1 and list 2, union all common numbers between list 1 and list N, then it's somewhat different:

```
var common = Enumerable.Empty<int>();
foreach (var list in lists.Skip(1))
{
    common = common.Union(lists.First().Intersect(list));
}
```

Comment: don't you need the union of all the intersects of 2 combinations?

Comment: @Jodrell: Good question. Initially I thought not (also, you probably mean "pairs of the first list with each of the others"?), now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
List<int> commonIds = list1.Intersect(list2.Intersect(list3)).ToList();
```

It's pretty efficient since it's using a set.

Comment: Why not chain the `Intersect` calls? ie `Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3)`

Comment: don't you need the union of all the intersects of 2 combinations?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: works also, it was just the first that came to my mind. Maybe my nested approach is more efficient but i doubt it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Jodrell was asking about an alternative interpretation of the question. If this was your interpretation, you really should be searching for and closing as a duplicate :p

Comment: @Rawling:  Yes, my interpretation was this because OP's pseudo code was rather clear. And no, i don't have always the time to search duplicates, OP should do that before asking.

Comment: I guess that's one way to get to 6-figure rep... "I don't have time to search for duplicates but I *do* have time to answer them"

Comment: @Rawling: If you are already quoting me, please don't drop relevant parts. I have said that i have **not always** the time to find the duplicates. As you can [see easily](http://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter?tab=votes&sort=closure) _sometimes_ i have the time. If a question seems rather clear and i know the answer, i will answer. If i have also the time to search if there is a duplicate i vote to close for duplicate, either before or after i've answered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function,

it returns the union of the intersect of all 2 set combinations.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SharedItems<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    var pairs =
            from s1 in source
            from s2 in source
            select new { s1 , s2 };

    var intersects = pairs
        .Where(p => p.s1 != p.s2)
        .Select(p => p.s1.Intersect(p.s2));

    return intersects.SelectMany(i => i).Distinct();
}
```

Comment: This will give the union of all the sets :)

Comment: No wait, it won't compile. `Union` doesn't work like that. But you also need to ensure `s1 != s2`.

Comment: @rawling, agreed, is that better?

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up with too :D

Answer (score -1):

to customize

```
void Main()
{
     List<int> one = new List<int>() {1, 3, 4, 6, 7};
     List<int> second = new List<int>() {1, 2, 4, 5};

     foreach(int r in one.Intersect(second))
        Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```