# Join an unknown number of sources when all sources contain given key

Tags: system.reactive

Given a source provider like below:

```
IObservable<ISource> Sources();
```

with each ISource looking like below:

```
IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> ObserveData(string filter)
```

I'd like to return:

```
IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> Results
```

when a given string is returned from all ISources. Essentially I want the intersection of all the sources.

If a new source is added then everything should re-evaluate.

I'm struggling to come up with a generic solution to this. Most solutions I've seen have a well known number of sources.
Any ideas appreciated.

**Answer**
Ok after thinking for a while longer I came up with my answer. Possibly it can be improved on but it seems to work for me so I'll post it here for reference in case someone else has a similar issue. Thanks to ibebbs and Shlomo for taking the time to reply, much appreciated.

```
 //Arrange
        var s1 = Substitute.For<ISource>();
        s1.ObserveData(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(Observable.Return(new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }));

        var s2 = Substitute.For<ISource>();
        s2.ObserveData(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(Observable.Return(new[] { "b", "xx", "c", "d" }));

        var s3 = Substitute.For<ISource>();
        s3.ObserveData(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(Observable.Return(new[] { "yy", "b", "ff", "d" }));

        var expected = new[] { "b", "d" };

        var sources = new[] { s1, s2, s3 }.ToObservable();

        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var observer = scheduler.CreateObserver<IList<string>>();

        //Act
        sources.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500), scheduler)
            .Select(s => Observable.CombineLatest(s.Select(x => x.ObserveData("NoFilter"))))
            .Switch()
            .Select(x =>IntersectAll(x))
            .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"Recieved {string.Join("," , x)}"))
            .Subscribe(observer);

        scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500).Ticks);

        //Assert
        observer.Messages.AssertEqual(
            OnNext<IList<string>>(0, s => s.SequenceEqual(expected)),
            OnCompleted<IList<string>>(0));
```

For IntersectAll, see [Intersection of multiple lists with IEnumerable.Intersect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect)

Comment: Is Results a property or a method? If a property, what should.be passed in for the filter argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, second attempt and I'm pretty sure this is what you need (test fixture included at the bottom):

```
public interface ISource
{
    IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> ObserveData(string filter);
}

public static class ArbitrarySources
{
    public static IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> Intersection(this IObservable<ISource> sourceObservable, string filter)
    {
        return sourceObservable
            .SelectMany((source, index) => source.ObserveData(filter).Select(values => new { Index = index, Values = values }))
            .Scan(ImmutableDictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>.Empty, (agg, tuple) => agg.SetItem(tuple.Index, tuple.Values))
            .Select(dictionary => dictionary.Values.Aggregate(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), (agg, values) => agg.Any() ? agg.Intersect(values) : values).ToArray());       
    }
}

public class IntersectionTest
{
    internal class Source : ISource
    {
        private readonly IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> _observable;

        public Source(IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> observable)
        {
            _observable = observable;
        }

        public IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> ObserveData(string filter)
        {
            return _observable;
        }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ShouldIntersectValues()
    {
        TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        var sourceA = new Source(scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            new Recorded<Notification<IEnumerable<string>>>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext<IEnumerable<string>>(new string[] { "a", "b" })),
            new Recorded<Notification<IEnumerable<string>>>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext<IEnumerable<string>>(new string[] { "a", "b", "c" }))
        ));

        var sourceB = new Source(scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            new Recorded<Notification<IEnumerable<string>>>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext<IEnumerable<string>>(new string[] { "a", "c" })),
            new Recorded<Notification<IEnumerable<string>>>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext<IEnumerable<string>>(new string[] { "b", "c" }))
        ));

        var sources = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
            new Recorded<Notification<ISource>>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext<ISource>(sourceA)),
            new Recorded<Notification<ISource>>(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2).Ticks, Notification.CreateOnNext<ISource>(sourceB))
        );

        var observer = scheduler.Start(() => sources.Intersection("test"), 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6).Ticks);

        IEnumerable<string>[] actual = observer.Messages
            .Select(message => message.Value)
            .Where(notification => notification.Kind == NotificationKind.OnNext && notification.HasValue)
            .Select(notification => notification.Value)
            .ToArray();

        IEnumerable<string>[] expected = new []
        {
            new [] { "a", "b" },
            new [] { "a" },
            new [] { "a", "c" },
            new [] { "b", "c" }
        };

        Assert.Equal(expected.Length, actual.Length);

        foreach (var tuple in expected.Zip(actual, (e, a) => new { Expected = e, Actual = a }))
        {
            Assert.Equal(tuple.Expected, tuple.Actual);
        }
    }
}
```

This approach has the added benefit of not re-querying existing sources when a new source is added but will recompute the intersection each time any source emits a value.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public IObservable<IEnumerable<string>> From(this IObservable<ISource> sources, string filter)
{
    return sources
        .Scan(Observable.Empty<IEnumerable<string>>(), (agg, source) => Observable.Merge(agg, source.ObserveData(filter)))
        .Switch();
}
```

Be aware, that every time a new source is emitted from `sources` all the sources that have been emitted previously will have their `ObserveData` method called again. Therefore this solution doesn't scale particularly well but does meet your 'If a new source is added then everything should re-evaluate' requirement

Comment: On first glance it looks like it will merge all the sources rather than find the intersection. So if source one outputs ["a","b","c"] and source two outputs ["b","a"] I'd only want to get ["a","b"].