# Comparing three lists

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to compare three lists and from these lists, trying to find the unique element.

As an example:

```
List A: 1 
List B: 1, 2
List C: 1, 2, 3
```

As a result, element "3" should be stored.

What I have attempted by looking at previous questions and expanding on is:

```
 Dim result1 As List(Of Long) = A.Except(B).ToList()
 Dim result2 As List(Of Long) = C.Except(result1).ToList()
```

The issue I face is my lists could be as such:

```
List A: 1
List B: 1
List C: 1, 2
```

As a result, result1 will store 0 which compares to list C and were then storing in result2: 1 and 2

Is it possible to compare three lists simultaneously? The except document on Microsoft states 2 lists only. Alternatively I could just do a pre check to see if A and B are the same and not to compare them but rather do a 3 way comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
ListA
  .Concat(ListB)
  .Concat(ListC)
  .GroupBy(Function(i) i)
  .Where(Function(g) Not g.Skip(1).Any())
  .Select(Function(g) g.Key)
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I've managed to get it building by putting your code on one line (VB doesn't recognise new lines unless you use _ ")

Can't give it a vote up yet due to lack of points but ive given it the green tick!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this...

```
Dim listOfLists = new List(Of List(Of Long))()From { _
    listA, _
    listB, _
    listC _
}
Dim resultList = listOfLists.Aggregate(Function(previousList, nextList) previousList.Intersect(nextList).ToList())
```

Jon Skeet has another approach, see [Intersection of multiple lists with IEnumerable.Intersect()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1674779/1350913) (C#)

Comment: I like your solutions better as its far easier to understand. Just having issues implementing it.

I had to make a modification for both variables as they wanted an As clause so there like this now: Dim listOfLists As List(Of Long) = ...

But im getting errors throughout the lines such as "overload resolution failed" due to too many operators