# Find common characters from group of string

Tags: c#, char

Given the set of below strings

```
vJrwpWtwJgWrhcsFMMfFFhFp
jqHRNqRjqzjGDLGLrsFMfFZSrLrFZsSL
PmmdzqPrVvPwwTWBwg
```

In above strings only lower case letter `"r"` is common in all of them.

I know we can use `Intersect`to find common things in **2** string but how to do using **3** strings?

This code below i did for 2 strings

```
var commonString = firstPartOfstring
  .Intersect(secondPartOfString)
  .Select(x => x)
  .FirstOrDefault()
  .ToString();
```

But cant find how to do for 3 strings

Comment: Use [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @KonradRudolph huh?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect

Comment: @Hogan Not sure what part of that is unclear. `Aggregate` generalises an operation of two operands to a set of inputs. Your solution works with exactly 3 inputs, but no longer works for an arbitrary number of inputs. That's where `Aggregate` comes in.

Comment: @KonradRudolph -- yes -- I believe you are saying to use Aggregate on a list of lists.  This question is about 3 lists.  A general case could be solved with aggregate but to anyone who is asking this question your comment's meaning is a mystery.

Comment: @James, that looks like the second puzzle of Advent For Code 2022, day 3 https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case you can *query* the strings (`lines`) with a help of Linq `Aggregate`. Please, note, that to get string from enumeration (`IEnumerable<char>`) we should use `Concat()`, not `ToString()`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// Organize the strings into a collection, say, an array 
// (Set, List etc. will do as well)
string[] lines = {
  "vJrwpWtwJgWrhcsFMMfFFhFp",
  "jqHRNqRjqzjGDLGLrsFMfFZSrLrFZsSL",
  "PmmdzqPrVvPwwTWBwg",
};

...

// Query the collection above with a help of Linq:
//   We turn each string into enumeration (IEnumerable<char>)
//   Aggregate all enumerations into one with a help of Intersect
//   Concat characters of the final enumeration to the string
string commonString = string.Concat(lines
  .Select(line => line.AsEnumerable()) // we deal with IEnumerable<char>, not string
  .Aggregate((s, a) => s.Intersect(a))
  .OrderBy(c => c) // In case you want common characters being ordered
);
```

if `null` can appear among the strings, change `.Select(...)` into

```
.Select(line => line?.AsEnumerable() ?? Array.Empty<char>())
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t8uhn6) youself.

If you want just to intersect three strings you can do it as follow:

```
string first = "vJrwpWtwJgWrhcsFMMfFFhFp";
string second = "jqHRNqRjqzjGDLGLrsFMfFZSrLrFZsSL";
string third = "PmmdzqPrVvPwwTWBwg";

string commonString = string.Concat(first
  .Intersect(second)
  .Intersect(third));
```

Answer (score 0):

Intersect is transitive -- that means you can string them together in sequence.

```
var commonString = firstPartOfstring
                  .Intersect(secondPartOfString)
                  .Intersect(thirdPartOfString)
                  .Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

(nb - you can sequence them in any order - the other attribute of transitive)